# Python - Keep date column and flip cells with field names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a schedule in a pandas dataframe.  The first column is the date and the other columns are the shifts: shift 1 shift 2, shift 3 etc.  Under the shifts are the employees: e1, e2, e3, etc.

My current data looks like this:

```
df
  calander_date s1  s2  s3  s4  s5  s6  s7  s8  s9
0 1/1/2020      e1  e3  e6  e2  Nan e7  e4  Nan e9
1 1/2/2020      e2  e8  e6  e4  Nan e5  e1  Nan e7
2 1/3/2020      e3  e10 e4  e2  Nan e7  e1  Nan e9
3 1/4/2020      Nan e10 e4  e2  e5  e7  e1  Nan e9
```

My goal is the keep the date as the first column and have the employees as the field names and have the shift worked under the employee like the following:

```
df
  calander_date e1  e2  e3  e4  e5  e6  e7  e8  e9
0 1/1/2020      s1  s4  s2  s7  Nan s3  s6  Nan s9
1 1/2/2020      s7  s1  Nan s4  s6  s3  s9  s2  Nan
2 1/3/2020      s7  s4  s1  s3  Nan Nan s6  Nan s9
3 1/4/2020      s7  s4  Nan s3  s5  Nan s6  Nan s9
```

Looking for a clever way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a combination of `melt/stack` and `unstack/pivot`:

```
(df.set_index('calander_date').replace('Nan', np.nan)
   .stack().reset_index(name='employee')
   .pivot('calander_date', 'employee','level_1')
)
```

Output:

```
employee       e1  e10  e2   e3  e4   e5   e6  e7   e8   e9
calander_date                                              
1/1/2020       s1  NaN  s4   s2  s7  NaN   s3  s6  NaN   s9
1/2/2020       s7  NaN  s1  NaN  s4   s6   s3  s9   s2  NaN
1/3/2020       s7   s2  s4   s1  s3  NaN  NaN  s6  NaN   s9
1/4/2020       s7   s2  s4  NaN  s3   s5  NaN  s6  NaN   s9
```